# Duplicate test output with minitest and rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, minitest

I'm experiencing some really unexpected behavior with Minitest's Spec syntax and Rails 5's ActiveSupport::TestCase.

Here's a ruby-only test using Minitest:

```rb
class MyTest < Minitest::Test
  describe "outer loop" do
    describe "inner loop" do
      it "works" do
        assert true
      end
    end

    it "still works" do
      assert true
    end

    it "sti" do
      assert true
    end
  end

  def test_no_work
    assert false
  end
end
```

It results as expected in the following:

```
...F

  1) Failure:
MyTest#test_no_work [my_test.rb:21]
Failed assertion, no message given.

4 runs, 4 assertions, 1 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

When testing a rails model and inheriting from ActiveSupport::TestCase, however, I get the following:

```
.F

Failure:
BlahTest::outer loop#test_no_work [/blah/test/models/blah_test.rb:21]
Expected false to be truthy.

..F

Failure:
BlahTest::outer loop::inner loop#test_no_work [/blah/test/models/blah_test.rb:21]
Expected false to be truthy.

F

Failure:
BlahTest#test_no_work [/blah/test/models/blah_test.rb:21]
Expected false to be truthy.

6 runs, 6 assertions, 3 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

exact same test code except for the first line:

```rb
class BlahTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
```

Is this a bug or am I missing something here?

**Update**:

Here is my test_helper.rb for reference:

```rb
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rails/test_help'
require 'minitest/spec'

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.yml for all tests in alphabetical order.
  fixtures :all

  # Add more helper methods to be used by all tests here...
  extend MiniTest::Spec::DSL

  register_spec_type(self) do |desc|
    desc < ActiveRecord::Base if desc.is_a?(Class)
  end
end
```

I modified it per this link: http://www.agustinvinao.com/rails-5-minitest-spec-fixtures which seems similar to what blowmage describes here: http://blowmage.com/2013/07/08/minitest-spec-rails4, except for this:

```
  class << self
    remove_method :describe
  end
```

which was supposed to fix `#describe` being defined by both ActiveSupport::TestCase and Minitest::Spec. This block breaks in Rails 5, however, with the following error:

```
`remove_method': method `describe' not defined in Class (NameError)
```

Comment: What command do you use to run tests? Eg.: `bin/rake test` or `bin/rails test` or without `bin/` Did you try to use `minitest-rails` gem?

Comment: @lependu I use `rails test` without the `bin/`, though trying other variations produced the same result. I did use minitest-rails (3.0) at first - and had the same issue - but later removed the gem and used a custom test_helper which I've added above.